# spring diasable logging for controller

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logging, log4j

There is a polling service which fills up my log

```
2022-01-09T05:24:32,827 DEBUG [ajp-nio-8009-exec-7] o.s.c.l.LogFormatUtils: GET "/VenusD/anonymous/
```

Somewhat like above. I just need to disable spring logging for a selected controller or request mapping.

What is the right way of doing it? How can I probably exclude it?

Comment: Can I know your log setting? I want to know why LogFormatUtils print out "GET "/VenusD/anonymous/". My console print out "org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.traceDebug - GET" in my setting

Comment: It also prints this o.s.w.s.h.AbstractHandlerMapping anyhow that is the short form package. How can I disable for one particular request mapping?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to change log level of package, comment please.

You can set log level of pacakge.

My log4j2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout
                pattern="[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}:%-3relative][%thread] %-5level %logger{100}.%M - %msg%n" />
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="console" />
        </Root>
        
        <!-- <Logger name="org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet" level="warn"></Logger>  -->
    </Loggers>

    
</Configuration>
```

My log, When I set log levl debug

```
[2022-01-09 10:01:34:5876][http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO  org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/].log - Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
[2022-01-09 10:01:34:5877][http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initServletBean - Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
[2022-01-09 10:01:34:5877][http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initMultipartResolver - Detected StandardServletMultipartResolver
[2022-01-09 10:01:34:5877][http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initLocaleResolver - Detected AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver
[2022-01-09 10:01:34:5877][http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initThemeResolver - Detected FixedThemeResolver
[2022-01-09 10:01:34:5877][http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initRequestToViewNameTranslator - Detected org.springframework.web.servlet.view.DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator@5889aa66
[2022-01-09 10:01:34:5878][http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initFlashMapManager - Detected org.springframework.web.servlet.support.SessionFlashMapManager@25bd45e9
[2022-01-09 10:01:34:5878][http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initServletBean - enableLoggingRequestDetails='false': request parameters and headers will be masked to prevent unsafe logging of potentially sensitive data
[2022-01-09 10:01:34:5878][http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initServletBean - Completed initialization in 1 ms
[2022-01-09 10:01:34:5890][http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.traceDebug - GET "/", parameters={}
[2022-01-09 10:01:34:5894][http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.getHandler - Mapped to com.example.rest.timeout.controller.ControllerTest#get()
[2022-01-09 10:01:34:5919][http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters - Using 'application/json;q=0.8', given [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/avif, image/webp, image/apng, application/xml;q=0.9, application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8] and supported [application/json, application/*+json, application/json, application/*+json]
[2022-01-09 10:01:34:5919][http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters - Nothing to write: null body
[2022-01-09 10:01:34:5921][http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.logResult - Completed 200 OK
```

My log, When I remove following comment in log4j2.xml

```
<!-- <Logger name="org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet" level="warn"></Logger>  --> 
to
<Logger name="org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet" level="warn"></Logger>
```

Debug log level of org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet is removed.

```
[2022-01-09 10:12:34:666106][http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO  org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/].log - Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
[2022-01-09 10:12:34:666108][http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.getHandler - Mapped to com.example.rest.timeout.controller.ControllerTest#get()
[2022-01-09 10:12:34:666109][http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters - Using 'application/json;q=0.8', given [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/avif, image/webp, image/apng, application/xml;q=0.9, application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8] and supported [application/json, application/*+json, application/json, application/*+json]
[2022-01-09 10:12:34:666110][http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters - Nothing to write: null body
```

Comment: If i change level for this package o.s.c.l. that will stop logging for all the controllers, which is not desired

Comment: @Aadam You can't stop logging for a selected controller, because The dispatcherServlet print out only that log when level of log is trace or debug not a selected controller.

Comment: Thankyou for your response, I am aware of that, I wanted to know if there is mechanism o r utils that can alter this behaviour for selected classes, like not logging or controlled logging for provided classes